# Data not transferred to table from file in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive

So I am just starting out with HIVE,

Here is what I do,

-> Load the file into HDFS:

> hadoop fs -put purchases.txt

-> Create a table:

```
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE p1(transaction STRING) STORED AS TEXTFILE
> LOCATION '/purchases.txt';
```

or

> CREATE TABLE p1(transaction STRING) STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION
>   '/purchases.txt';

-> Show the table:

> show tables;

At this point it shows me the table p1 has been created.

-> Viewing Contents

`select * from p1`

It just outputs

```
OK
Time taken: 0.175 seconds
```

EDIT:

The data is stored in this format:

> date '\t' time '\t' store '\t' item '\t' cost

I would like to take the whole line as a single string and hence i've specified only one string column.

Answer (score 2):

The location of a Hive table should be specified as a directory, not an individual file. Hive will then read every file in that directory. For example:

create the directory:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /p1
```

put the file in the directory:

```
hadoop fs -put purchases.txt /p1
```

create the hive table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE p1(transaction STRING)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/p1';
```

Most tools in the hadoop world tend to operate on directories instead of individual files. That way, hadoop itself can manage how many files are read/written and what they are named.

Comment: Just to add to the original query `hadoop fs -put purchases.txt` puts it under the /user/<username>/ folder and not in the root of HDFS.

Comment: I've done that as well. Using only the directory! But the data still won't show up only an ok command and time taken.

Comment: Thanks @PraveenSripati ! But how do I put it in the root of HDFS ? I did move it to a separate folder called purchases after moving it in HDFS. And I do specify the directory. 
But the data won't show in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following query you will be able to see the data populate in your table:

```
create external table p1 (
  transaction String
)
location '/purchases.txt';
```

NOTE: There are several other ways in which you can do table creation and load data into the table. I had just specify the solution for approach you took. Try exploring them.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Happy Hadooping!!!!!

Comment: I tried this too but the data isn't being copied. I've edited and added a little more info on the file if thats helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command instead; should work:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE p1(transaction STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/p1'
```